# Tips when input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input, when I write text I want to show some tips
For example days of week
I have some array in JS

```
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thusday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
```

and I have input

```
<input type="text" required="required" id="type" name="type"/>
```

And I want, when I start to write word in input, to see the tips from my array.
How it is possible in Jquery?
I understand how I can do in AngularJS, but I need in Jquery

Comment: you mean autocomplete?

Comment: You can do so using autocomplete. you can find example here to show from array using jquery. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: you can use  https://select2.github.io/

Comment: @Viking I have prepared jsfiddle demo and also wrote code in answer, it should solve your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thusday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
  ];
  $("#days").autocomplete({
    source: days
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" required="required" id="days" name="type" />
```

For more information you can check : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thank you very much. It is possible to do writing two words? For example MondayFriday or other?

Answer (score 1):

I have created jsfiddle demo to demonstrate how you can achieve it.

Link: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zrz9t/3834/)

You can do it using below code.

HTML Code:

```
<body>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input type="text" required="required" id="type" name="type" />
  </div>
</body>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thusday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  $("#type").autocomplete({
    source: days
  });
});
```

This should help you.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `input` event to detect input and show tooltip:

```
$('[type="text"]').input(function(event){
    //code to display tooltip
});
```